# Hibernate Reverse Engineering - How do I reverse engineer a link/join table to include a set in each primary class

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I have 3 tables in my DB: User, UserRole and UserRoleMapping.
UserRoleMapping contains the association between users and their roles.

In my Java Wicket app, I want to use hibernate reverse engineering to generate classes and xml mappings (i'm using netbeans). In doing so, I want the reverse engineering to create a set in each of the base classes as follows:

```
User {
   ...

   Set <UserRole> userroles = new HashSet(0);

}
```

AND

```
UserRole {
    ...
    Set <User> users = new HashSet(0);

}
```

What do I need to do in my hibernate.reveng.xml class to get this right?

NB: I am not using any wizard to generate a reveng file and I am not using eclipse.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The UserRoleMapping must

1. have field for userid
2. have field for roleid
3. do not have any other fields
4. must be unique constraint for userid and roleid
5. Both fields must be "not-null"
6. both fields must be have a foregin key(innodb only) for the pk's of their opposite tables.